# How do I define an FSCheck generator so that it can be discovered

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'm writing an FSCheck generator to create strings having the following properties:

- They are non-null
- Trimming them won't affect the length
- They contain no spaces.

Here's my generator code:

```
namespace Example

open FsCheck.Arb

module public Generation = 

    let hasChars (s : string) =
        (isNull s |> not)
        && s.Length > 0

    let isTrimmed (s : string) =
        s.Trim().Length = s.Length

    let isContinuous (s : string) =
        s
        |> Seq.exists ((=) ' ')
        |> not

    [<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
    type public Generators = class end

    type public ContinuousString = ContinuousString of string with
        member x.Get = match x with ContinuousString r -> r
        override x.ToString() = x.Get

    type public Generators with

        static member ContinuousString() =
            Default.String()
            |> filter hasChars
            |> filter isTrimmed
            |> filter isContinuous
            |> convert ContinuousString string
```

And here's a test intended to verify the generation:

```
[<Property(Arbitrary=[| typeof<ContinuousString> |], MaxTest=2)>]
let ``A continuous string contains no spaces`` (s: ContinuousString) =
    s.Get.Contains " " |> not
```

When I run this test, I get:

```
System.Exception: No instances found on type Example.Generation+ContinuousString. Check that the type is public and has public static members with the right signature.
```

As far as I can tell looking at the FSCheck source code, the member I have defined should be found by the discovery filter, and the method seems analogous to similar built-in ones such as `NonEmptyString`.

What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: I think `typeof<ContinuousString>` should be `typeof<Generators>`. Also, I don't think you need to define it twice: the `type public Generators = class end` definition is doing nothing for you, AFAIK.

Comment: Also: `isNull s |> not` could be just `s <> null`. Also: `ContinuousString.Get` is a property, but named like a method. Also: you don't actually need `Get`, you could define the test function's parameter as `(ContinuousString s)` instead of `(s: ContinuousString)`.

Comment: Great, thanks @rmunn!  The corrected `typeof<>` fixed it.  The empty type was just there so I was replicating what FSCheck's own code as closely as possible - I didn't expect it to have an effect.  If you want to transfer your comment to an answer I'll mark as accepted.  Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, done. Looks better as a real answer anyway, but a comment was the fastest way to get you the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing FsCheck the wrong type. You should be passing it your `Generators` class, not your `ContinuousString` DU. I.e., this:

```
[<Property(Arbitrary=[| typeof<ContinuousString> |], MaxTest=2)>]
let ``A continuous string contains no spaces`` (s: ContinuousString) =
    s.Get.Contains " " |> not
```

should have been:

```
[<Property(Arbitrary=[| typeof<Generators> |], MaxTest=2)>]
let ``A continuous string contains no spaces`` (s: ContinuousString) =
    s.Get.Contains " " |> not
```

The FsCheck error message was trying to tell you this as well:

> Check that the type is public and has public static members with the right signature.

The type that you created that matches what it's looking for is `Generators`.